# Qt5 on Linux - where is Linguist?

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, linux-mint, linguistics

I'm using Linux Mint 16 and I got a problem.
I installed Qt Creator 5.2.1 from binary package, downloaded from Qt site. I don't have Qt Linguist... Also, I have installed qtcreator and qt5-dev-tools (or similar name) from repository, still no Linguist. Where I can download it?
I prefer binary version from Qt site because it's newer than version from repository.

Comment: It should be in the bin directory of Qt installation (binary package). For me, it is in `<qt_install_dir>/5.3/gcc_64/bin`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be in the bin folder. You can always do this to figure it out:

```
find $installdir/ -name \*linguist\*
```

By the way, there is also another option: install Archlinux and get all the fancy latest stuff. ;-)